# Mocked component appearing as null in WebMvcTest

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm testing a controller `JmxController` which calls a service `JmxService` which in turn calls a component `CrfVerifier`. The component unfortunately is throwing an NPE despite the fact I have mocked it.

**JmxControllerTest.java**

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = JmxController.class, secure = false)
public class JmxControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private JmxControlToolService jmxControlToolService;

    @MockBean
    private JmxControlService jmxControlService;

    @MockBean
    private CrfVerifier crfVerifier;

    @Test
    public void shouldThrowInvalidCrfExceptionForJmxOperationWhenCrfInvalidAndOperationIsCritical() throws Exception {
        //when
        when(jmxControlToolService.getJmxOperationsAndAttributes(anyString(), anyString(), anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(buildOperationsAndAttributesList());
        when(jmxControlToolService.executeOperation(any())).thenCallRealMethod();

        doNothing().when(crfVerifier).verifyCrf(anyString(), anyString());

        //then
        mockMvc.perform(post("/jmx/execute-jmx-operation")
                .etc()
}
```

**JmxController.java**

```java
    @PostMapping("/execute-jmx-operation")
    public JmxOperationResponseDto executeJmxOperation(@RequestBody JmxOperation jmxOperation) {
        return jmxControlToolService.executeOperation(jmxOperation);
    }
```

**JmxServce.java**

```java
public JmxResposneDto executeOperation(JmxDto jmxDto) {
...
        crfVerifier.verifyCrf(jmxExecutedOperationDto.getCrfNumber(), jmxDto.getApplication()); //NPE on crfVerifier
...
}
```

**CrfVerifier.java**

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class CrfVerifier {

    private final ServiceNowRestClient serviceNowRestClient;

    public void verifyCrf(String str1, String str2) {
         ... 
    }
```

I've tried using a `@TestConfiguration` and using `@Import` on the class but still I get an NPE in JmxService.

I don't understand how the mocked service doesn't throw an NPE but the mocked component does. Can anyone point me in the direction of the resolution?

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried using a @TestConfiguration and using @Import on the class
> but still I get an NPE in JmxService.

Your `JmxControllerTest` mocks a bean of type `JmxControlService`. As it is defined as a mock, the *mocked bean* `CrfVerifier` is not injected in the *mocked bean* `JmxControlService`. Mocked beans are not constructed like a normal Spring bean would; they are merely added to the TestApplicationContext as "empty" beans on which test logic can be defined.

In your test you indicate that when `jmxControlToolService.executeOperation` is invoked, the actual method should be called instead of relying on mocked behaviour:

```java
when(jmxControlToolService.executeOperation(any())).thenCallRealMethod();
```

However, as the method requires an instance of `crfVerifier`, the NullPointerException is thrown.

I would suggest to use a [`@SpyBean`](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-spy) on the `JmxControlService`, or adjust the scope of the test. For instance, if the purpose of your test is to test the interaction between the `JmxController` controller and the `JmxControlToolService`, you could mock the beans *required* by the service instead of the Service itself.